# Cannot read properties: 'Service_State__c'

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I am getting a error: `"[Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Service_State__c')]"`

I'm not sure where its coming from, but I am guessing its has something to do with my array not having all 9 spots filled.

***The error message:***

[image]

**The Whole MapMarkers.js Code:**

```
// This function is for inputting the map-markers for the 9 most recent "Opportunities", and for the search location on the map.
export function MapMarkers(SearchCity, SearchState, SearchStreet, Opportunities, UpdateOpportunities){

   // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

   //================ ** Still in work ** =====================

   // Array Variables.
   let NineRecentOpportunities;
   let validStages;
   let validCity;
   let validState;

   if(UpdateOpportunities == true){

       // Sets the 9 most recent "Signed" opportunities from the searched 'City & State' to the array.
       validStages = ['Signed', 'Signed LOI'];
       validCity = [SearchCity];
       validState = [SearchState];
       NineRecentOpportunities = Opportunities.filter(
       (record) => (

           validCity.indexOf(record.Service_City__c) > -1 && 
           validState.indexOf(record.Service_State__c) > -1 && 
           validStages.indexOf(record.StageName) > -1

       )).slice(-9);

   } else {

       // Sets the 9 most recent "Signed" opportunities to the array.
       validStages = ['Signed', 'Signed LOI'];
       NineRecentOpportunities = Opportunities.filter(
       (record) => validStages.indexOf(record.StageName) > -1 ).slice(-9);

   }

   console.log('new_9:',  NineRecentOpportunities);

   // Todo:
   // ----(2)----
   // What to do: A boolean value inside the searchclick method.
   // Create a array to store any Opportunities that match the State and City, of "SearchState" and "SearchCity". 
   // ----(3)----
   // Find out if a for-loop inside "mapMarkers" is possible, so the code can be shrunk.

   const ArrAddress = [];

   // This for-loop creates a address string, and stores them to an array.
   for (let i = 0; i < NineRecentOpportunities.length; i++) {

       ArrAddress[i] = NineRecentOpportunities[i].Service_Street__c + ', ' + NineRecentOpportunities[i].Service_City__c + ', ' + NineRecentOpportunities[i].Service_State__c + ', USA';

   }


   //================ ** Still in work ** =====================

   // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

   const mapMarkers = [
       {
           // ----- When searching is done. -----
           location: {

               State: SearchState,
               City: SearchCity,
               Street: SearchStreet,
               Country: 'USA',

           },

           value: 'Search',
           title: 'Searching Marker',
           description: "Address: ".bold() + "<br/>" + SearchStreet + ', ' + SearchCity + ', ' + SearchState + ', USA',
           // fillColor: '#CF3476',
           // icon: 'WES_Headquarters.png',
               
       },

       {
           // ----- Opportunity 1. -----
           location: {

               State: NineRecentOpportunities[0].Service_State__c,
               City: NineRecentOpportunities[0].Service_City__c,
               Street: NineRecentOpportunities[0].Service_Street__c,
               Country: 'USA',

           },

           value: 'Opportunity1',
           title: NineRecentOpportunities[0].Name,
           description: "Service Address: ".bold() + "<br/>" + ArrAddress[0] + "<br/>" + "Project Type: ".bold() + NineRecentOpportunities[0].Project_Type__c + "<br/>" + "Signed Date: ".bold() + NineRecentOpportunities[0].Actual_Contract_Signed_Date__c,
           // fillColor: '#CF3476',
           // icon: 'WES_Headquarters.png',
               
       },

       {
           
           // ----- Opportunity 2. -----
           location: {

               State: NineRecentOpportunities[1].Service_State__c,
               City: NineRecentOpportunities[1].Service_City__c,
               Street: NineRecentOpportunities[1].Service_Street__c,
               Country: 'USA',
   
           },

           value: 'Opportunity2',
           title: NineRecentOpportunities[1].Name,
           description: "Service Address: ".bold() + "<br/>" + ArrAddress[1] + "<br/>" + "Project Type: ".bold() + NineRecentOpportunities[1].Project_Type__c + "<br/>" + "Signed Date: ".bold() + NineRecentOpportunities[1].Actual_Contract_Signed_Date__c,
               
       },

       {
           
           // ----- Opportunity 3. -----
           location: {

               State: NineRecentOpportunities[2].Service_State__c,
               City: NineRecentOpportunities[2].Service_City__c,
               Street: NineRecentOpportunities[2].Service_Street__c,
               Country: 'USA',
           },

           value: 'Opportunity3',
           title: NineRecentOpportunities[2].Name,
           description: "Service Address: ".bold() + "<br/>" + ArrAddress[2] + "<br/>" + "Project Type: ".bold() + NineRecentOpportunities[2].Project_Type__c + "<br/>" + "Signed Date: ".bold() + NineRecentOpportunities[2].Actual_Contract_Signed_Date__c,
               
       },

       {
           
           // ----- Opportunity 4. -----
           location: {

               State: NineRecentOpportunities[3].Service_State__c,
               City: NineRecentOpportunities[3].Service_City__c,
               Street: NineRecentOpportunities[3].Service_Street__c,
               Country: 'USA',
   
           },

           value: 'Opportunity4',
           title: NineRecentOpportunities[3].Name,
           description: "Service Address: ".bold() + "<br/>" + ArrAddress[3] + "<br/>" + "Project Type: ".bold() + NineRecentOpportunities[3].Project_Type__c + "<br/>" + "Signed Date: ".bold() + NineRecentOpportunities[3].Actual_Contract_Signed_Date__c,
               
       },

       {
           
           // ----- Opportunity 5. -----
           location: {

               State: NineRecentOpportunities[4].Service_State__c,
               City: NineRecentOpportunities[4].Service_City__c,
               Street: NineRecentOpportunities[4].Service_Street__c,
               Country: 'USA',
   
           },

           value: 'Opportunity5',
           title: NineRecentOpportunities[4].Name,
           description: "Service Address: ".bold() + "<br/>" + ArrAddress[4] + "<br/>" + "Project Type: ".bold() + NineRecentOpportunities[4].Project_Type__c + "<br/>" + "Signed Date: ".bold() + NineRecentOpportunities[4].Actual_Contract_Signed_Date__c,
               
       },

       {
           
           // ----- Opportunity 6. -----
           location: {

               State: NineRecentOpportunities[5].Service_State__c,
               City: NineRecentOpportunities[5].Service_City__c,
               Street: NineRecentOpportunities[5].Service_Street__c,
               Country: 'USA',
   
           },

           value: 'Opportunity6',
           title: NineRecentOpportunities[5].Name,
           description: "Service Address: ".bold() + "<br/>" + ArrAddress[5] + "<br/>" + "Project Type: ".bold() + NineRecentOpportunities[5].Project_Type__c + "<br/>" + "Signed Date: ".bold() + NineRecentOpportunities[5].Actual_Contract_Signed_Date__c,
               
       },

       {
           
           // ----- Opportunity 7. -----
           location: {

               State: NineRecentOpportunities[6].Service_State__c,
               City: NineRecentOpportunities[6].Service_City__c,
               Street: NineRecentOpportunities[6].Service_Street__c,
               Country: 'USA',
   
           },

           value: 'Opportunity7',
           title: NineRecentOpportunities[6].Name,
           description: "Service Address: ".bold() + "<br/>" + ArrAddress[6] + "<br/>" + "Project Type: ".bold() + NineRecentOpportunities[6].Project_Type__c + "<br/>" + "Signed Date: ".bold() + NineRecentOpportunities[6].Actual_Contract_Signed_Date__c,
               
       },

       {
           
           // ----- Opportunity 8. -----
           location: {

               State: NineRecentOpportunities[7].Service_State__c,
               City: NineRecentOpportunities[7].Service_City__c,
               Street: NineRecentOpportunities[7].Service_Street__c,
               Country: 'USA',
   
           },

           value: 'Opportunity8',
           title: NineRecentOpportunities[7].Name,
           description: "Service Address: ".bold() + "<br/>" + ArrAddress[7] + "<br/>" + "Project Type: ".bold() + NineRecentOpportunities[7].Project_Type__c + "<br/>" + "Signed Date: ".bold() + NineRecentOpportunities[7].Actual_Contract_Signed_Date__c,
               
       },

       {
           
           // ----- Opportunity 9. -----
           location: {

               State: NineRecentOpportunities[8].Service_State__c,
               City: NineRecentOpportunities[8].Service_City__c,
               Street: NineRecentOpportunities[8].Service_Street__c,
               Country: 'USA',
   
           },

           value: 'Opportunity9',
           title: NineRecentOpportunities[8].Name,
           description: "Service Address: ".bold() + "<br/>" + ArrAddress[8] + "<br/>" + "Project Type: ".bold() + NineRecentOpportunities[8].Project_Type__c + "<br/>" + "Signed Date: ".bold() + NineRecentOpportunities[8].Actual_Contract_Signed_Date__c,
               
       },

   ];

   return mapMarkers;

}
```

**The SearchClick method in the Mapping.js File:**

```
// Method for when the search button is clicked in the "mappingBox" LWC.
    SearchClick(message) {

        if(message.operator == true){

            // The address entered into the search bar.
            const ArrStreet = SearchString.split(',');
            SearchStreet = ArrStreet[0];

            // The town or city entered into the search bar.
            const ArrCity = SearchString.split(',');
            SearchCity = ArrCity[1];

            UpdateOpportunities = true;

            // Updates and locates the location searched.
            this.mapMarkers = MapMarkers(SearchCity, SearchState, SearchStreet, ClickData, UpdateOpportunities);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't the loop, it's the fact that your `mapMarkers` is *not* being created in a loop. You've hard-coded 9 spots, and you expect all of them to be filled. Instead, you need some kind of loop to create the entries until you run out of entries.

Here's an example refactor of your code. Don't worry, I'll explain it all after the break.

---

```
// This function is for inputting the map-markers for the 9 most recent "Opportunities", and for the search location on the map.
export function MapMarkers(
  SearchCity,
  SearchState,
  SearchStreet,
  Opportunities,
  UpdateOpportunities
) {
  let validStages = new Set(["Signed", "Signed LOI"]);

  const filterA = (record) =>
    record.Service_City__c === SearchCity &&
    record.Service_State__c === SearchState &&
    validStages.has(record.StageName);
  const filterB = (record) => validStages.has(record.StageName);

  let NineRecentOpportunities = Opportunities.filter(
    UpdateOpportunities ? filterA : filterB
  )
    .slice(-9)
    .map((record) => ({
      ...record,
      address: `${record.Service_Street__c}, ${record.Service_City__c}, ${record.Service_State__c}, USA`,
    }));

  const mapMarkers = [
    {
      location: {
        State: SearchState,
        City: SearchCity,
        Street: SearchStreet,
        Country: "USA",
      },
      value: "Search",
      title: "Searching Marker",
      description: `<b>"Address: "</b><br />${SearchStreet}, ${SearchCity}, ${SearchState}, USA`,
    },
    ...NineRecentOpportunities.map((record, index) => ({
      location: {
        Street: record.Service_Street__c,
        City: record.Service_City__c,
        State: record.Service_State__c,
        Country: "USA",
      },
      value: `Opportunity${index}`,
      title: record.Name,
      description: `<b>Service Address:</b><br/>${record.address}<br/>
                    <b>Project Type:</b>${record.Project_Type__c}<br/>
                    <b>Signed Date: </b>${record.Actual_Contract_Signed_Date__c}`,
      // fillColor: '#CF3476',
      // icon: 'WES_Headquarters.png',
    })),
  ];
  return mapMarkers;
}
```

## Set

A set lets us write cleaner looking code. You should definitely use it for situations where you're looking for a value in a set of values. It takes a single parameter, an array, and stores only the unique values.

## Arrow Function

It's like a regular function, but cleaner, and preserves `this` properly. Here, we define `filterA` and `filterB` for the next step, the filter method. The syntax we use here is `(parameters) => expression`. Other forms of arrow functions also exist. You may use `{}` for multiple lines of code, `({})` for an Object constructor, and `[]` for an Array.

## Ternary operator (?:)

We use this like a shorthand if-else statement. Since the logic differed only by the data we checked for, we can switch the parameter to filter by simply checking which we should use. The full syntax is `condition? valueWhenTrue: valueWhenFalse`.

## Array.filter

Accepts a function that returns a true value if the entry should be retained. `filterA` and `filterB` effectively demonstrate two different behaviors.

## Array.slice

I mentioned this before, but basically, we're just grabbing a number of items. Negative numbers count from the end, and can't return more elements than there are in the original Array.

## Array.map

Transforms one object into another, copying into a new array. Here, we use this to create an `address` property so that we don't need the address Array you created. Everything is now in one object.

## REST operator

`...` indicates that some kind of collection of the rest of the items is happening. In general, we have `[...Iterable]`, `{...Object}`, and `(...params)`. We're only using two of the three types here. You'll see `{...record` where we copy the record to add the the address property, and we use `[...NineRecentOpportunities]` to create a total of 10 markers, the search boundary and the 9 locations.

$ `string` (Template literals)

We use `` ` `` to indicate a template literal. At any point, we can use `${}` to jump into JavaScript to do something. As a quick example:

```
var x = 5;
var y = `x is ${x}`;
console.log(y); // "x is 5"
```

This is really useful for longer strings rather than trying to quote everything and use the `+` operator.

Comment: Thank you, the example code you gave is working correctly. The only issue I'm running into is when I use the search feature, my "Signed Opportunities" from the same City/State aren't populating. Any Ideas?

Comment: @Pinto JavaScript is, by default, case sensitive. try: `record.Service_City__c?.toLowerCase() === SearchCity?.toLowerCase() &&
    record.Service_State__c?.toLowerCase() === SearchState?.toLowerCase() && validStages.has(record.StageName);`

Comment: I made the changes in `filterA`, and its still not populating. Should `.toLowerCase()` be used in the `mapMarkers` variable too?

Comment: @Pinto No, because the records would already have been filtered out by then. The problem is further up the chain, from the place where you're calling this method.

Comment: Ok, I'm guessing its in my `mapping.js` file, in the `SearchClick` method. I have `UpdateOpportunities = true;` is something wrong with that Boolean?

Comment: @Pinto That part looks fine. How is `SearchClick` being called?

Comment: I updated the question above to include the whole method, I'm and trying to pass `UpdateOpportunities` to the `MapMarkers` function, and it looks like its coming out as "undefined", then "true" when the button is clicked.

Comment: @Pinto I've seen SearchClick, I was asking about how that code gets executed to begin with. FYI, there's a convention that variables start with a lowercase letter, while classes start with an uppercase letter. This isn't enforced by JavaScript itself, but following these conventions makes it easier to read your code.

Comment: **Update:** I looked into it, and the `SearchCity` variable had a extra white space from the start of the string. So I used the `.trim()` method, and that fixed it! Thank you!